# Scoping - querying nested documents performance impact?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to mirror the data of an external database through their API.

However, I also want to store a few extra fields on each document. I figured the structure would be easier to reason about, if there was a clear distinction between the data supplied by the API and the extra fields I have attached.

Example:

```js
Schema({
  youtube: {
    type: Object
  },
  'youtube.etag': {
    type: String
  },
  'youtube.commentThreadId': {
    type: String,
    index: 1
  },
  'youtube.channelId': {
    type: String,
    index: 1
  },
  'youtube.videoId': {
    type: String,
    index: 1
  },
  'youtube.canReply': {
    type: Boolean
  },
  'youtube.totalReplyCount': {
    type: Number
  },
  'youtube.isPublic': {
    type: Boolean
  },
  lastSync: {
    type: Date,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  },
});
```

In my case, scoping the API data on 'youtube' as an embedded document seemed to do the trick, but I would like to know if their is any performance hit by doing this, compares to having the fields at the outermost level of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Organizing your data into sub-documents like this is a good idea and has no effect on performance.

However, your schema structure is invalid because you can't have `.`s in your key names. It should be defined like this instead:

```js
Schema({
  youtube: {
    etag: String,
    commentThreadId: {type: String, index: 1},
    channelId: {type: String, index: 1},
    videoId: {type: String, index: 1},
    canReply: Boolean,
    totalReplyCount: Number,
    isPublic: Boolean
  },
  lastSync: {
    type: Date,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  },
});
```